# python manage.py runserver not printing

Tags: django

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd ~/Desktop
PS C:\Users\Owner\Desktop> cd ./mywebsite
PS C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\mywebsite> ls


Directory: C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\mywebsite


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        6/11/2018   2:35 PM                .idea
d-----        6/11/2018   1:57 PM                mywebsite
-a----        6/11/2018   1:37 PM            252 manage.py


PS C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\mywebsite> python manage.py runserver
PS C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\mywebsite>
```

I am trying to get to the web page that should be created for me, but the runserver function is not printing any information for me to get to there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you do a `python --version`, `pip list` and `python manage.py runserver --verbosity 3` (Maximum verbosity)?

Comment: Can you try this python manage.py runserver 8000

Comment: It shows my python version as Python 3.7.0b2. The pip list shows django(1.9), pip(9.0.1), setuptools (28.8.0). Maximum verbosity does the same thing as the regular runserver.

Comment: 'Python manage.py runserver 8000' prints out nothing too.